# How to count section pages in LaTeX and display them in a progress bar?

Tags: counters, bar

I am currently writing a student work in latex as a scrartcl. I would like to make an overview in my document of how many pages I still have to write in each section. So like an actual/target comparison. This should count the pages of the individual sections and show me for each section on a progress bar how many percent I have already written of this chapter in relation to my plan. I think of the overview as on the picture, where on the left side is the total progress and on the right side the bars which represent the progress of the individual sections.

[image]

I've only seen such a thing with beamers for the whole document. Did any of you do anything similar and have any idea how I could implement it?